# Images don't work on iPhone but they do work on Android?

Tags: android, html, css, iphone

CSS, the user presses a spot and an image should appear

```
 .img1 {
      background: url(../images/11.jpg)100% 100%/100% no-repeat;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 100px;
      width: 38%;
    }

    .img1:active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

> HTML code with class .img1

```
<div class="electronic">
      <p>CONTABILIDAD ELECTRONIC</p> <div class="img1> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything, because there is not element with class "img1".

Comment: i forgot to write down, but I did use an element <div class="img1> </div>, yet it won't work on iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```css
 .img1 {
      background: url('/file.jpg')100% 100%/100% no-repeat;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 100px;
      width: 38%;
    }

    .img1:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="electronic">
      <p>CONTABILIDAD ELECTRONIC</p><div class="img1"> </div>
    </div>
```

The image is displayed when it is clicked at the bottom of the text !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and I want to share the solution: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart 
I used a javascript event called touchstart that magically worked for IOS